# Filter queryset based on related object's field value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I have two models:

```
class PartUse(models.Model):
    ...
    imported = models.BooleanField()


class PartReturn(models.Model):
    partuse = models.ForeignKey(PartUse)
    ...
    imported = models.BooleanField()


class PartUseListView(ListView):
    model = PartUse

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.GET.get('show_imported', None):
            qs = self.model.objects.all()
        else:
            qs = self.model.objects.filter(Exists(PartReturn.objects.filter(
                imported=False, id__in=OuterRef("partreturn"))))
        return qs
```

I want to filter QuerySet for `PartUse` to return all `PartUse` instances that have `imported == False` for either model. What's the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter `PartUse` instances that have `imported == False` for either model, you can use Django's [`Q()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) objects to perform a query with `OR` logic.

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class PartUseListView(ListView):
    model = PartUse

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.GET.get('show_imported', None):
            qs = self.model.objects.all()
        else:
            qs = self.model.objects.filter(Q(imported=False) | Q(partreturn__imported=False))
        return qs.distinct()
```

Here, `distinct()` method is used to avoid duplicate results.